# How to properly unwrap error code from boost exception

Tags: c++, boost, exception

The question is simple, yet I cannot figure out how to do it. I want to get the system_error, and from there get the concrete error code. I have something like this in the error:

```
Dynamic exception type: boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::current_exception_std_exception_wrapper<std::runtime_error> >
std::exception::what:
boost::system::system_error
```

I can catch a `boost::exception` but not `std::runtime_error` or a `boost::system_error` directly:

```
try {

        this->service_.run();
    }
    catch (boost::system::system_error const & e) {
                i_->playerLog->info("Exiting with system error. Error code: {} -- What: {}", e.code().value(),
                                    e.what());
            }
 catch (boost::exception const & e) {
    i_->playerLog->info("Exiting with boost exception: {}", boost::diagnostic_information(e));
 }
```

My code will enter boost::exception clause, but never system_error or runtime_erro

Comment: and what is the origin of the exception?

Comment: good question... I guess it is from boost.asio. The code is quite complex though.

Comment: How do you know it won't catch a `std::runtime_error`?  I ask only because the code shown doesn't have an explicit `catch` clause for it.

Comment: @G.M. yes, it is catching a `std::runtime_error`, I just tried. I think I can dynamic_cast to boost::system_error and unwrap from there.

Comment: Might give useful information to print out `typeid(e).name()` in some catch clause that successfully caught the thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be no problem:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9fb31be175a824b8)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    try {
        using namespace boost::asio;
        io_service svc;
        ip::tcp::acceptor a(svc);
        a.open(ip::tcp::v4());

        a.bind({{}, 22}); // error, need admin privs
    } catch(boost::system::system_error const& e) {
        std::cout << e.what() << ": " << e.code() << " - " << e.code().message() << "\n";
    }
}
```

Prints

```
bind: Permission denied: system:13 - Permission denied
```

If it doesn't, usually you have some kind of mix of dynamically loaded libraries with unmatching type information.

### BONUS

For completeness, tested with more elaborate exception information: **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f182a40de0e65447)</kbd>**